# Ionic React Overmind Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I use [Overmind](https://overmindjs.org/) with ionic react:

Tab1:

```js
const { count } = useAppState()
const { increaseCount } = useActions()

return
<IonPage>
  <IonContent>
    <IonRouterLink routerLink='/tab1/page1'>1. Go to another page</IonRouterLink> // Go to page 1
    <IonText><p>{count}</p></IonText>
    <IonButton onClick={() => increaseCount()}>4. Increase again</IonButton>
  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
```

Page2:

```js
const { count } = useAppState()
const { increaseCount } = useActions()

return
<IonPage>
  <IonContent>
    <IonBackButton defaultHref="/" /> // Go back to tab 1
    <IonText><p>{count}</p></IonText>
    <IonButton onClick={() => increaseCount()}>4. Increase again</IonButton>
  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
```

When I do this:

1. Go to the other page
2. Increase the count (modify state)
3. Go back to main page
4. Increase the count (modify state)
   ==> Go to console and there is the error

```yaml
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

I created this minimum reproduction code: https://github.com/dopeshot/ionic-overmind-cant-perform-state-update

I also created an short video of the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5w6r1_lxoS8

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is a bug in the overmind-react library. If you go to the source code, you can see they don't set the `mountedRef.current` to false when the component unmounts, so when the state changes it tries to rerender the unmounted component. It should be right here
https://github.com/cerebral/overmind/blob/cb095ffa0cd49504fed6bbc99054d89ba9b92ea3/packages/overmind-react/src/index.ts#L139

You could clone the repo, add the following change to the code, and point the dependency to your version in a git repository (or publish your own package)

```
    return () => {
        mountedRef.current = false;
        overmind.eventHub.emitAsync(EventType.COMPONENT_REMOVE, {
```

The best would be to open a GitHub issue and, if possible, open the PR with that small change. But I wouldn't expect it to be addressed soon since it seems to be a problem that happens only in development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to be the problem... However when I place `mountedRef.current = false;` into it I'll still get the same error :/

Comment: @LarsFlieger how did you try it? because it's working for me

Comment: I took my minimum reproduction code and "hot fixed" it inside node_modules... Is this way not working?

Comment: @LarsFlieger to hotfix it that way, you need to make the changes in two files, one is `/node_modules/overmind-react/es/index.js` and the other `/node_modules/overmind-react/lib/index.js`, and then clear the node modules cache to make sure to recreate the bundle `rm -rf node_modules/.cache`

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to clear the bundle.. Works now! Thank you very much! Solved the issue. I also created a pr for all other people using overmind with react: https://github.com/cerebral/overmind/pull/545

Answer (score -1):

you need to **NOT** update the state in the callback if the component is not mounted already.

as the error state:

> Error Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted
> component.

#### solution

Declare let `isMounted = true` inside `useActions` (or `useEffect`, using `useAction` is not advised, and not really supported anymore, you can read [redux's creator comment on this](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1252#issuecomment-488160930)), which will be changed in the cleanup callback, as soon as the component is unmounted. Before state updates, you now check this variable conditionally:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isMounted = true;               // note mutable flag
  someAsyncOperation().then(data => {
    if (isMounted) setState(data);    // add conditional check
  })
  return () => { isMounted = false }; // cleanup toggles value, if unmounted
}, []);                               // adjust dependencies to your needs
```

**more thorough solution**: Custom `useAsync` Hook
We can encapsulate all the boilerplate into a custom Hook, that automatically aborts async functions in case the component unmounts or dependency values have changed before:

```
function useAsync(asyncFn, onSuccess) {
  useEffect(() => {
    let isActive = true;
    asyncFn().then(data => {
      if (isActive) onSuccess(data);
    });
    return () => { isActive = false };
  }, [asyncFn, onSuccess]);
}
```

Comment: How is this related to my issue? I'm not doing any async jobs?

Comment: its just an example of an action I had, you can change it to what ever you'd like

Comment: by the way, from the error messege it seems like you do have an asynchronous job (or a subscription)